# Indices of igraph transitivity

Tags: r, igraph

I have list of large dataframes each with many rows of data that look like this

```
structure(list(from = c(6972, 48591, 2016, 48591), to = c(791, 
234, 3304, 234), time = c(1521763200, 1521781282, 1521781543, 
1521781548)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I´m aiming to transform the data into graphs and the calculate transitivity for each vertex in the graph. Right now I´m doing this

```
emails<-lapply(ldf,function(x){x %>% group_by(from,to) %>% summarize(weight = n())}) #where ldf is the list of df
gemails<-lapply(emails, function(x){graph_from_data_frame(x,directed=TRUE)})

clustering <- lapply(gemails, function(x){transitivity(x,type="local")})
```

While I seem to be getting the transitivity values, I do not know to which vertex does each value correspond. I know that not all the numbers exist in "to" or "from" so I do not know with which vertex to pair the result

I will also want to calculate the transitivity with only the vertex present in "from" or "to" that are less than a number x (e.g. 4000), but I have not been able to do it. I´ve created a list of the indices I want, and I´ve tried to pass the list of vertices with `vids=` but it does not seem to work. I´ve also try with just passing 1:4000 to vids but it does not work.

Comment: If you have a graph `g`, then `V(g)` will tell you which vertex lines up with which result from `transitivity`. I'm not sure about passing `vids=` but you probably need to reference the name of the vertex - `V(g)[as.numeric(V(g)$name) < 4000]` for instance.

Comment: That actually does the trick! Thank you